# Can't make Angle object in Manim, is the class deprecated or am I missing something?

Tags: python, manim

Pretty new to Manim and trying to make an *Angle* object like it says on the documentation:
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.geometry.line.Angle.html?highlight=angle#manim.mobject.geometry.line.Angle.from_three_points

But getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'Angle' is not defined
```

Here's the line of code I used:

```
self.play(ShowCreation(Angle(nueva_linea2, nuevo_radio)))
```

(Being 'nueva_linea2' and 'nuevo_radio' two *Line* objects)

As you may already suspect, the following won't work either:

```
angulo = Angle(nueva_linea2, nuevo_radio)
self.play(ShowCreation(angulo))
```

Here's the Manim version according to the terminal:

```
ManimGL v1.6.1
```

Comment: Looks like you need to `import` it.

Comment: Tried `from manimlib import Angle` but got the error `ImportError: cannot import name 'Angle' from 'manimlib'`. It seems weird eitherway that all of the other objects like Line or Dot work but Angle doesn't.

Comment: Manimgl is a different fork than manim community. The documentation you linked is for manim community. Maybe that's the problem?

Comment: It actually seems to be. Thanks for the response!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The community maintained version ("Manim") is different from Grant's version ("ManimGL" / "manimlib"). In ManimGL, there is no `Angle` mobject.

See here for more information: https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/faq/installation.html#why-are-there-different-versions-of-manim

Comment: Ok, I suspected that may be the reason. Thanks for the response and the link!